# How to use "allow-return-values="true"" in TestNG test methods?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am beginner to [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/index.html). I about test method in official TestNG documentation. I am not clear with the use of `allow-return-values="true"` can any one explain it briefly with example. I did one example I didn't get way the way of using,

This is my .xml

```xml
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="newSuite" parallel="methods" thread-count="5" allow-return-values="true">
<parameter name="browser" value="Firefox"></parameter>
<test name="dataprovider" allow-return-values="true">
   <classes>
      <class name="com.tets.SampleTest"></class>
   </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

and my test class is as follows,

```java
public class SampleTest {

@AfterMethod
public void teardown(Object returnValueFromTest){
    //inspect returnValueFromTest and perform necessary clean up.
}


@Test
public String testEventGeneration(){
    //generate event

    //returning generated e vent id.
    return "E1234";

}

@Test
public String testMarketGeneration(){
    //generate market

    //returning generated market.
    return "hai";
}}
```

How and where can I get the return value from `testMarketGeneration` test method ?

Answer (score 1):

The option 'allow-return-values' is not meant to test the return value "hai". It is meant to allow @Test annotation on methods that have return values.

By default TestNG follows best practices for unit testing, which means a unit test method should not have a return value. However sometimes you want to add the @Test annotation to a method with a return value. If you do not specify 'allow-return-values' in your Suite configuration TestNG will print out a warning and will not run the method as tests.

The warning TestNG gives is something like:

> Method public java.util.List a.B.getC(java.util.List) has a @Test annotation but also a return value: ignoring it. Use 'suite allow-return-values="true"' to fix this

The only useful example of allowing return values I have found so far is when your test class implements a certain interface and you want to test all interface methods by adding @Test annotations.

See http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html for the real documentation.